# Increase the value in spreadsheets (+1) when choose a specific name from a drop-down list

Tags: excel

I have sheet for tasks
and I want to track when choose a specific name from a drop-down list increase value +1
something like 
if (A1==Tom) increase B1= value +1
else (A1==Jack) increase B2= value +1
.....

Answer (score 1):

I made a chore list for my kids a while back, the same logic may apply to what you are working on here.

I used the 'countif' function to monitor a range and if a criteria (name) appeared it added 1.

See if this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(A1="Tom",B1+1,IF(A1="Jack",B2+1,IF(A1="Ben",B3+1,...)))))))`

(one closing bracket for each name input)

this is basically a manual countif,

ergo: you could also use countif

Comment: This does not increment the cells B1 and B2 as the OP wants.

Comment: that's what you'd think, however OP specified that "if (A1==Tom) increase B1= value +1 else (A1==Jack) increase B2= value +1 ....." so try to understand what that means before jumping to conclusions